# How to find location of snippet in directory?

Tags: sublimetext2

How to find a snippet's location in directory? I know its scope and trigger key but can't seem to find it.

Any way to do it without going through all directories one-by-one?

Answer (score 1):

Snippets are defined in `.sublime-snippet` files, and are stored in the `Packages/<Language Name>` directory of the language they are associated with. For example, the PHP `do-while` snippet is stored in `Packages/PHP/do-while(-).sublime-snippet`. Depending on the language, snippets may be stored in the base directory, or in a `Snippets/` subdirectory, or some other place in the hierarchy, as ST2 searches the full directory tree for them.

Of course, if you want to find all `.sublime-snippet` files, the following command will do it nicely when executed in the `Packages` directory on OSX/Linux:

```
find . -name *.sublime-snippet -print
```

For Windows, just use the Find Files feature in Windows Explorer.